# Can I use lenses from a Canon Rebel XS on a Canon EOS 80D?

Tags: canon

So I’m thinking to buy a Canon EOS 80D camera. I already have some lenses for the Canon that I have, and I’m not sure if the lenses that I own will fit the Canon EOS 80D. Will they fit or not? The Canon that I have now is a Canon Rebel XS.

Comment: If you don't have too many Canon lenses, or your lenses are particularly inexpensive (eg, the kit lenses), you can consider jumping ship.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Both cameras you mention use EF-S lens. And just for the record you can also use EF lens on EF-S socket camera.